# Is it possible to chain locators with seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, seleniumbase

I've tried to transfer my selenium code into seleniumbase however I'm receiving
"Message: invalid argument: invalid locator" when I try to chain locators.

seleniumbase code:

```
 def get_products(self, sb):
        return sb.find_elements("//div[@class='card h-100']")

products = shop_page.get_products(sb)
        print(len(products))  # 4
        if len(products) > 0:
            for product in products:
                print(product)
                if product.find_element("div/h4/a").text == 'Blackberry':  # this line causes error
                    return ShopPage.add_to_cart(product)
```

I've been using locators chaining in raw selenium and it worked fine.

```
    def get_products(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card h-100']")

    def add_blueberry(products):
        if len(products) > 0:
            for product in products:
                if product.find_element(By.XPATH, "div/h4/a").text == 'Blackberry':
                    return ShopPage.add_to_cart(product)
        else:
            raise Exception("No products found!")
```

url: https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing APIs. With SeleniumBase, you don't need to specify the `by`, as it autodetects the selector, but with regular webdriver and WebElement commands, you do.

So once you actually find a list of elements with SeleniumBase, each item is a WebElement, and you would need to do:

```py
if product.find_element(By.XPATH, "div/h4/a").text == 'Blackberry':
```

(It would be the same for both SeleniumBase and raw Selenium.)

However, the SeleniumBase way of simplifying that would be something like:

```py
products = self.find_elements("//div[@class='card h-100']//div/h4/a")
for product in products:
    print(product.text)
```

The output of that on that page is:

```
iphone X
Samsung Note 8
Nokia Edge
Blackberry
```

So rather than chaining selectors in separate commands, put the full selector in the initial `self.find_elements()` call.